# How can I return response from Angular factory?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following factory function:

```
var getCompanyList = function () {

    return $http.get(config.apiUrl + 'Company/GetListofCompanyNames');
};
```

I'm currently calling it via

```
companyService.getCompanyList().then(function(response) {
                $scope.CompanyList = response.data;
            },
            function(error) {
                $scope.errors = "Oops! Something went wrong... " + error.statusText;
            });
```

Is it possible to do the following:

```
$scope.CompanyList = companyservice.getCompanyList();
```

Comment: That would require it to be synchronously, or it would require you to do some magic like Angular Resources used to do.
Using callbacks is the way to do it these days, even though it makes your code less readable.

Comment: Gotcha, not 100% sure why angular can't execute an api call > get a 200 > return data > return a function (like most compiling programming languages), but I'm relatively new to it, so I'll stick with the callbacks, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I haven't looked if there's a an option to make it synchronously. But on the web the reason is the same as in compiled languages. If you'd do the call synchronously, you're gui would freeze.

Comment: Although I hear there's an async feature coming to js that may give a similar experience to C# async await. I need to look into it.